# How to extract a specific line from the python output

Tags: python

I am trying to execute this `curl` command using `python`. It retrieves an output like below.

```
import subprocess

try:
    output=subprocess.check_output(["curl", "-v", "https://escortpersonaladz.com"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(output)
    if "expire date:" in str(output):
        print("Found") 
        print("Expiry date is: ") # I want to extract and print ONLY expiry date from the output
    else:
        print("Not found")
except:
    print("Error Occured")
```

this produces below output

```
* Rebuilt URL to: <dns>
*   Trying <ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to escortpersonaladz.com (<ip>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=webdisk.escortpersonaladz.com
*  start date: May  3 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "escortpersonaladz.com" matched cert's "escortpersonaladz.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
.
.
.
Found
Expiry date is:
```

How can I extract that particular line `*  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT` from the above output and write it to a file, so that file would look like:

```
1         *  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
2         *  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2022 GMT
3         *  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
.
.
.
```

Comment: convert into dictionary and get the value from the dictionary of value.

Comment: @DipenShah how can I convert this to a `dictionary` ?

Comment: use with the type conversion like this -> output_dic = dict(output)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the lines using something this:

```
string = '''
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=webdisk.escortpersonaladz.com
*  start date: May  3 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "escortpersonaladz.com" matched cert's "escortpersonaladz.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
'''
for line in string.split('\n'):
    if line[0:15] == '*  expire date:':
        print(line)
>>> *  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
```

You can save these lines in a file to a variable and create a text file like:

```
text = ''
for line in string.split('\n'):
    if line[0:15] == '*  expire date:':
        text += line + '\n'

file = open('filename.txt', 'r+')
file.truncate(0)
file.seek(0)
file.write(text)
file.close()
print(text)
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this and let know

Comment: This is not working as my string is not in the format of yours. Imagine the string is a one line

Comment: Hmmm. Can you do me a favour and show me your code please? If possible also use `print(repr(foobar))` on variables so I can see whats up with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do that:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

```py
x = re.sub(<Matching regex>, <The part you want>, output)
print(x)
```

Comment: Can you provide the matching regex?

Comment: `re.sub()` uses to replace a text. How do I use this to achieve what I want?

Comment: You have to select the part you want, and remove everything else. Here you have some example: https://github.com/nkmk/python-snippets/blob/457f0f79b485ed639a366b48495646769a32dac4/notebook/str_re_sub.py#L17-L21

Comment: The regex would be sth like:   ```python
x = re.sub(".*\*  (expire date .* GMT) .*", "\\1", output)
print(x)
```

Comment: This is not working, this regex doesn't work. Did you try this?

Comment: No, that's why I said is "sth like" take a look to the documentation of re.sub() but it can do the job